# Shame cannot survive empathy

Tags: phrase-meaning

I heard that saying in a TED talk and I can't understand it's meaning!

The phrase is:

**shame cannot survive empathy**

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I can only presume the downvotes are for lack of context. I guess the shame of downvoting with no explanation was overcome by the empathy of fellow downvoters! Can you provide a link to the talk or a complete sentence to give context?

Comment: sorry I didn't mean that !https://youglish.com/search/shame%20cannot%20survive%20empathy%20/us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means when you feel shame and someone understands your feelings, the shame is no longer justified.